# Search of a set of strings in a column containing strings in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe

I have a df with multiple columns, one of which is a string with many words(text column).

I also have a set of words, S, that I need to look for.

I want to extract the rows of the df that contain at least one word from S in its text column

`df_filtered=df[df['text'].str.contains('word')]`

This works for one word from the set S. Instead of looping over S, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match full words, use:

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, S))

df_filtered = df[df['text'].str.contains(fr'\b(?:{pattern})\b')]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `|` to represent `or` in regex

```py
df_filtered = df[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(S))]
```

Comment: Thank you @ynjxsjmh, How do I narrow this down if I want only whole word matches? For eg, now if S contains the word sun, df_filtered has rows that contain sunrise as well. But I want only those rows with "sun" as a word in it

Comment: @rse You can try mozway's answer which uses word boundary.